# TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined -

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When I'm checking the output of var it's showing the object

Code
`{JSON.stringify(todo)}`

Output:
`{"data":{"listNotes":[{"id":"001","name":"Note 1","completed":false},{"id":"002","name":"My note","completed":false}]}}`

Error when doing map on it, the output is can't map property of undefined

`{todo.map(data=>{return(JSON.stringify(data)})}`

Error

**TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined**

Comment: Why do you stringify it then? map() method is available on Arrays

Comment: That means that `todo` is undefined

Comment: Include your `todo` output

Comment: are you trying to iterate over `listNotes` ?

Comment: ozgur stringify it to just check todo containing anything or not

Comment: yes ozgur trying iterate